# Issue in test class - Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Map<ANY,ANY>

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex class like that :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static WrapperFilters manageFilters(Map<String, Object> lines){
   Map<Object, Object> mapLineDetail = new Map<Object, Object>();
    //iterate through inserted lines
    for(String key : lines.keySet()){
        mapLineDetail = (Map<Object, Object>)lines.get(key); //line where the test class fail
        //other code like that :
        if(mapLineDetail.get('ObjectName') == 'Account') {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the test method for this method :

```
@isTest static void manageFilters_Test() {
    LCR01_AccountList.WrapperLine wrapLine = new LCR01_AccountList.WrapperLine();
    wrapLine.ObjectName = 'Opportunity';
    wrapLine.FieldName = 'Amount';
    wrapLine.Operator = '<';
    wrapLine.Value = '10000';

    system.debug('### wrapLine : ' + wrapLine);

    Map<String, Object> mapFilters = new Map<String, Object>();

    String filter = '{FieldName=AccountId, FieldType=, ObjectName=Opportunity, Operator==, Value=0016E00000TIZUYQA5}';
    Object myObj = filter;
    System.debug('### myObj : ' + myObj);
    mapFilters.put('1', myObj);

    Test.startTest();
    LCR01_AccountList.WrapperFilters wrap = LCR01_AccountList.manageFilters(mapFilters);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

The problem is when I run the test class I got this error :

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Map

I test many things but I can't get over this error. The test fail at the line indicated in the apex method `mapLineDetail = (Map<Object, Object>)lines.get(key);`

I specify that the code (apex class) actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to cast the result of `lines.get(key)` into a `Map<Object, Object>`, whereas actually it is of the `String` type.

Just notice how you initialize it in your test:

```
Map<String, Object> mapFilters = new Map<String, Object>();
String filter = '{FieldName=AccountId,...}';
Object myObj = filter;
mapFilters.put('1', myObj);
```

Here `myObj` is a String

So you should do  `mapLineDetail = (String)lines.get(key);` instead.

**UPDATE:**

When you declare and initialize `String filter = '{FieldName=AccountId,...}';` it creates just a string, but in fact your code expects the `filter` argument to be `Map<Object,Object>`.

So all you need to do in you test class is update the line `String filter =` with:

```
Map<Object,Object> filter = new Map<Object,Object>{'FieldName'=>'AccountId', 'FieldType'=>'datetime', 'ObjectName'=>'Opportunity', 'Operator'=>'=<', 'Value'=>'0016E00000TIZUYQA5'};
```

Comment: Actually I need mapLineDetail  to be a Map<Object, Object> because I use it later in the code...

Comment: then you need to think about altering your implementation. As a quick fix, you can do mapLineDetail = new Map<Object,Object> {<some key>, lines.get(key)};

Comment: If I do that, it works for the unit test, but in real test it does not work anymore

Comment: Maybe because in a real run it is not get executed (e.g. your code never calls the manageFilters method, or the lines parameter is empty)?

Comment: no it is called (by lightning component) and it's not empty

Comment: then in a real run the lines.get(key) returns Map<Object,Object> and not String. Can you check it?

Comment: yes it returns something like that : `{FieldName=CreatedDate, FieldType=datetime, ObjectName=Opportunity, Operator=<, Value=2018-07-02T13:17:00.000Z}` (when I put a debug log on it)

Comment: Aha, try this in your test class Map<Object,Object> filter = new Map<Object,Object>{'FieldName'=>'AccountId', 'FieldType'=>'datetime', 'ObjectName'=>'Opportunity', 'Operator'=>'=<', 'Value'=>'0016E00000TIZUYQA5'};

When you create String filter = '{FieldName=AccountId,...}'; it creates just a string, whereas your code expects the filter to be Map<Object,Object>